# really merge in .bat file

Tags: batch-file

How do I merge two text files in a .bat file?
Or at least how to read the next line/test end of file in a .bat file?

Is it possible to merge two text files using a .bat script?
The idea is not to append, or concatenate but perform a merge operation based on the contents of each line. 
A simplified example would be to to produce a sorted file from two sorted files, like in the pseudo code (pseudo as I can’t seem to find a way to *read the next line* and test the end of the file read – outside a for loop)

```
:TOP
 Set /p  Line1 Read_Line (file1)
:set /p  Line2 Read_Line (file2)
:TEST
 IF EOF(file1) GOTO  FINISH2
 IF EOF (file2) GOTO FINISH1
 IF  %Line1%  < %Line2% 
        (echo %Line1% - not in 2 >> File3
        set  /p Line1 =Read_Line (file1)
        GOTO TEST)
ELSE IF %Line1%  > %Line2% 
        (echo %Line2% - not in 1>> File3
        set  /p Line2=Read_Line (file2)
        GOTO TEST)
ELSE echo %Line1% in both >> File3
GOTO TOP
:FINISH1
echo %Line2% - not in 1>> File3
        set /p Line1=Read_Line (file1)
        IF NOT (EOF (File1)) 
                (echo %Line1% - not in 2 >> File3
                 GOTO FINISH1)
ELSE GOTO EOF
:FINISH2
           echo %Line2% - not in 1>> File3
        set /p Line2 =Read_Line (file2)
        IF NOT (EOF (File1) )
                (echo %Line2% - not in 1 >> File3
                 GOTO FINISH2)
```

I tried with for loops, but branching inside loops seems to stop the loop. I tried various things (including a parallel .bat) to find a way to move the cursor inside the file using `set`  and `<` but can’t find how to do it right.

Comment: Why not simply use a diff/merge utility?

Comment: Welcome user1495762. Please use the markdown of this side, as offered by buttons above your editbox but not some self invented syntax which doesn't work. Read the FAQ for further information. Thank you.

Comment: There are some GNU tool: `join`, `sort -m`, `combine` etc. You can get most my installing cygwin. cygwin also comes with a nicer shell / command line interpreter called bash.

Comment: `sort` has also been in dos for quite a while - in XP, it would be `copy file1.txt+file2.txt file3.txt` then `sort file3.txt /o sortedfile3.txt` and the original files don't need to be sorted

Comment: @SeanCheshire - But that does not merge the files. If a line appears in both sources, it should only appear once in the output. Your suggestion would put 2 copies of the line in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Batch is really a terrible "language" to use for text processing. Nearly any other tool you can find would be better (easier to develop and faster to execute) than batch. I provide batch solutions because I enjoy the challenge, but I would always recommend some other language or tool over batch for text processing. That being said...

Assuming both source files have already been sorted.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::define the files
set "in1=file1.txt"
set "in2=file2.txt"
set "out=file3.txt"

::define some simple macros
set "eof1=^!ln1^! gtr ^!cnt1^!"
set "eof2=^!ln2^! gtr ^!cnt2^!"
set "read1=if ^!ln1^! leq ^!cnt1^! set "txt1=" & <&3 set /p "txt1=" & set /a ln1+=1"
set "read2=if ^!ln2^! leq ^!cnt2^! set "txt2=" & <&4 set /p "txt2=" & set /a ln2+=1"
set "write1=echo(^!txt1^! - not in 2"
set "write2=echo(^!txt2^! - not in 1"
set "writeBoth=echo(^!txt1^! - in both"

::count the number of lines in each file
for /f %%N in ('find /v /c "" ^<"%in1%"') do set "cnt1=%%N"
for /f %%N in ('find /v /c "" ^<"%in2%"') do set "cnt2=%%N"

::setup redirection in outer block and merge the files in a loop
::The max number of iterations assumes there is no overlap (cnt1+cnt2)
::Break out of the loop as soon as both files have reached EOF.
set /a ln1=0, ln2=0, cnt=cnt1+cnt2
4<"%in2%" 3<"%in1%" (
  %read1%
  %read2%
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do (
    if %eof1% (
        if %eof2% goto :break
        %write2%
        %read2%
    ) else if %eof2% (
        %write1%
        %read1%
    ) else if .!txt1! lss .!txt2! (
        %write1%
        %read1%
    ) else if .!txt2! lss .!txt1! (
        %write2%
        %read2%
    ) else (
        %writeBoth%
        %read1%
        %read2%
    )
  )
) >"%out%
:break
```

Use of SET /P to read the files has the following restrictions:

- Lines from both files must be terminated by `<carriage return><line feed>` characters (Windows style). It will not work with lines terminated by `<line feed>` (Unix style).
- Maximum 1021 bytes (characters) per line, not including line terminators
- Trailing control characters will be stripped from each line.

---

EDIT

If you simply want to create a sorted merged document without duplicates, then I beieve the following is an optimized version of [sean's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11298874/1012053). It is not nearly as elegant as his, but I believe it is much faster. It also allows each line to begin with any character by setting the EOL option to a `<line feed>`. Note that this solution strips all blank lines from the output (as does sean's). Additional code could be added to preserve a single blank line.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set lf=^


::above 2 blank lines required
copy /b file1.txt+file2.txt file3.txt >nul
set "old="
(
  for /f eol^=^%lf%%lf%^ delims^= %%A in ('sort file3.txt') do (
    set "new=.%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if "!old!" neq "!new!" echo(!new:~1!
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ("!new!") do (
      endlocal
      set "old=%%B"
    )
  )
)>file4.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

2 steps (sorting not needed, as the `find` in step 2 checks the new file, and only writes something if the data is not found):

1. merge the files:
   `copy file1.txt+file2.txt file3.txt`
2. Remove duplicate lines (`/i` ignores case, omit if `Fred` and `FRED` are to be treated as different):

   ```
   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (file3.txt) do (
     find /i "%%a" file4.txt>>nul&&rem
     if errorlevel 1 echo %%a>>file4.txt
     )
   ```

resultant file is `file4.txt`

Comment: +1, Elegant solution for a simple merge, assuming all dups should be removed. Not sure about performance though, calling FIND for each line might slow it down considerably. This cannot keep track of which lines come from where as the OP originally showed in pseudo code. Use COPY /B option to prevent addition of `<Ctrl-Z>`. Loop body can be simplified to `find /i "%%a" file4.txt>nul||echo %%a>>file4.txt`

Comment: woops, final output needs to be sorted to meed OPs requirement

Comment: `sort file4.txt /o file5.txt`, but your solution is way more elegant